# How to fetch old data from twitter

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am using [tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html) api to fetch old tweets

Here is my code which only fetching around most recent 3200 tweets from twitter.

**Code :**

```
import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import pymssql

#Twitter API credentials
access_key = ''
access_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

#connect to local database
conn = pymssql.connect('(local)','','','mydbname')
x = conn.cursor()

def get_all_tweets(sc):
    
    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  
    
    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = sc,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    
    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    
    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
        
        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = sc,count=200,max_id=oldest)
        
        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
        
        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        
        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    print len(alltweets)

    #save tweets to database
    for tweet in alltweets:
            insert_post_details(tweet)
    
#insert tweets data into database
def insert_post_details(tweet):
    try:
        qry="INSERT INTO MPTTwitterPosts(Id,Created_At,Favorite_Count ,Retweet_Count,Text) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        x.execute(qry, (str(tweet.id), tweet.created_at,tweet.favorite_count,tweet.retweet_count,str(tweet.text.encode("utf-8","ignore"))))
        conn.commit()
    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("Google")
```

If I tried to get older tweets with max_id,it is giving blank list of tweets

so How can I get old tweets, any suggestion would be greatly helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: is your issue that you are not getting any tweets, or that you are exceeding the rate limit?

Comment: @asongtoruin If I try to fetch records from old tweet id, it is giving empty list.

Comment: how about if you use `api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)`

Comment: @asongtoruin Still no Use of that on getting old tweets. Can you post your answer in the detail way for getting tweets of Google. I got 3245 tweets with last old tweet id = 839669148737277953 on 2017-03-09 02:48:20.000 , so how can i find old tweets before that tweet